# Why doesn't Uvicorn pick up Changes to CSS files?

Tags: css, fastapi, reload, uvicorn

I'm using FastAPI and the Uvicorn server to build a website, but when I make changes to the CSS files and reload the webpage it doesn't pick up these changes.

In fact, even when I switch off the server and reload it, Uvicorn still doesn't pick up the changes to the CSS file.

Previously, the server picked up the changes fine, what's caused this to change?

Comment: It seems this is actually a problem with the refresh button on the browser I'm using!

Comment: shift+reload usually makes the browser skip the local cache and reloads from the server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is not with Uvicorn, but with your web browser stashing 'static' files in its cache.

FastAPI uses a [method](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/static-files/) that designates a directory the 'static folder'. This tells the server that the files in this directory should remain constant and don't need to be downloaded every time a webpage is loaded.

Check inside your app's main module and look for the following piece of code:

```
app.mount(
    "/your_static_file_web_path",
    StaticFiles(directory="your_static_directory"),
    name="your_name_for_static_app"
)
```

This function creates a second FastAPI app within your pre-existing one that handles all of your static files. The second argument defines your static file directory. Anything within that directory will eventually be cached by your web browser and further changes will not be loaded. This prevents your page from loading the updated CSS.

As noted in a comment above, if you want to work around this issue, you can hold shift and reload the web page - this is known as a [hard refresh](https://fabricdigital.co.nz/blog/how-to-hard-refresh-your-browser-and-clear-cache). A hard refresh will force your browser to re-download everything, including static files.

Comment: Wasn't aware of that hard reload, thanks!